# How can I update a Django user's password from inside Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, passwords

I'd like to reset a user password, but only have access to the Postgres database. Dropping in plaintext doesn't work, and the hashing process for Django appears to be too complex to replicate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the ability to reset the password (or set a new password) any other accounts? If so, you could set the password you want on a different new account, and then take the hashed password in the db from that new account and set it as the password of the account you want to update.

Comment: @RossMechanic - unfortunately not.

Comment: You can probably generate a password with django on your local computer and then put that value in the db. Django saves all the information about a hash in the generated password, so it should work. At least that's what I gather from this document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords

Answer (score 0):

> the hashing process for Django appears to be too complex to replicate

If this is true, then I think the definitive answer is "You can't change it from inside PostgreSQL".

Answer (score -1):

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User  

    u = User.objects.get(username="username")
    u.set_password("New Password")
    u.save()
```

Comment: That would be the commands for the django shell, but not for within postgres.